# Why is slice faster than view() when constructing a multidimensional array from a vector?

Tags: arrays, julia, slice

Consider the following `Vector`:

```
numbers = Int32[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

If I want to create a `2x5` matrix with the result:

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
```

I can't use `reshape(numbers,2,5)` or else I'll get:

```
1 3 5 7 9 
2 4 6 8 10
```

Using `slice` or `view()`, you can extract the top row and bottom row, convert them to a matrix row, and then use `vcat()`.

I'm **not** saying using `slice` or `view()` is the only or best way of doing it, perhaps there is a faster way using `reshape()`, I just haven't figured it out.

```
numbers = Int32[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

println("Using Slice:")
@time numbers_slice_matrix_top = permutedims(numbers[1:5])
@time numbers_slice_matrix_bottom = permutedims(numbers[6:10])
@time vcat(numbers_slice_matrix_top,numbers_slice_matrix_bottom)

println("Using view():")
@time numbers_view_matrix_top = permutedims(view(numbers,1:5))
@time numbers_view_matrix_bottom = permutedims(view(numbers,6:10))
@time vcat(numbers_view_matrix_top,numbers_view_matrix_bottom)
```

**Output**:

```
Using Slice:
  0.026763 seconds (5.48 k allocations: 329.155 KiB, 99.78% compilation time)
  0.000015 seconds (3 allocations: 208 bytes)
  0.301833 seconds (177.09 k allocations: 10.976 MiB, 93.30% compilation time)
Using view():
  0.103084 seconds (72.25 k allocations: 4.370 MiB, 99.90% compilation time)
  0.000011 seconds (2 allocations: 112 bytes)
  0.503787 seconds (246.63 k allocations: 14.537 MiB, 99.85% compilation time)
```

Why is `slice` faster? In a few rare cases `view()` was faster, but not by much.

From [`view()`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/arrays/#Views-(SubArrays-and-other-view-types)) documentation:

> For example, if x is an array and v = @view x[1:10], then v acts like
> a 10-element array, but its data is actually accessing the first 10
> elements of x. Writing to a view, e.g. v[3] = 2, **writes directly to
> the underlying array** x (in this case modifying x[3]).

I don't know enough, but from my understanding, because `view()` has to convert the `Vector` to a matrix row (the original `Vector`) through another array (the `view()`), it's slower. Using `slice` we create a copy and don't have to worry about manipulating the original `Vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your results actually show that `view` is faster not slicing. The point is that only the second tests is measuring the time to run the code while in the tests 1 and 3 you are measuring the time to compile the code.

This is a common misunderstanding how to run benchmarks in Julia. The point is that when a Julia function is run for the first time it needs to be compiled to an assembly code. Normally in production codes compile times do not matter because you compile only once for a fraction of a second and then run computations for many minutes, hours or days.

More than that - your code is using a global variable so in such a microbenchmark you are also measuring "how long does it take to resolve a global variable type" which is slow in Julia and not used in a production code.

Here is the correct way to run the benchmark `using BenchmarkTools`:

```
julia> @btime vcat(permutedims($numbers[1:5]),permutedims($numbers[6:10]));
  202.326 ns (7 allocations: 448 bytes)

julia> @btime vcat(permutedims(view($numbers,1:5)),permutedims(view($numbers,6:10)));
  88.736 ns (1 allocation: 96 bytes)
```

Note the interpolation symbol `$` that makes `numbers` a type stable variable.

Comment: When you use `$` to make numbers a type stable variable, do you mean so that `BenchmarkTools` can see it as an `Int32[]`?

Comment: As far as I know it brings the variable to a local scope, so the code block within `@btime` can be efficiently compiled. In Julia (and in other dynamically typed languages) one should avoid using global scope variables and use functions instead.  Another option is to define `numbers` as `const numbers = Int32[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` - in that case you can avoid using  the`$` sign in your benchmarks.

Answer (score 0):

`reshape(numbers, 5, 2)'` can be used also to create the desired `2x5` matrix.